# Find all Wikilinks of DBPedia resource, where Wikilinks share same subject

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to execute this DBPedia SPARQL query below, but am getting an error. What am I doing wrong? Using the [DBPedia SPARQL Query Editor](https://dbpedia.org/sparql)

Also, I'd like to not have to re-inject the item again, but just reference the items listed in the parent/original FILTER.

```
-- find all wikilinks of resource, where wikilinks share same subject

SELECT ?item ?resource ?title ?snippet
WHERE { 
?item <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLink> ?resource . 
?resource <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?title . 
FILTER (?item IN (<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Artificial_intelligence>)) 
?resource <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?snippet
?resource <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?resourceSubject 
FILTER (
  ?resourceSubject IN (
    SELECT ?subject WHERE { 
        ?item2 <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?subject . 
        FILTER (?item2 IN (<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Artificial_intelligence>)) 
    }
  )
)
FILTER(LANG(?snippet) = "en") 
FILTER(LANG(?title) = "en")
}
```

Comment: you can't use a subquery in a filter expression. From where do you have this syntax? This is not SQL. And indeed a trailing dot after `?snippet` var is also missing

Comment: why not using a good old join for this? like this `SELECT ?item ?resource ?title ?snippet
WHERE { 
?item <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLink> ?resource . 
?item <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?subject . 
FILTER (?item IN (<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Artificial_intelligence>)) 
?resource <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?title . 
?resource <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?snippet.
?resource <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?subject .
FILTER(LANG(?snippet) = "en") 
FILTER(LANG(?title) = "en")
}`

Comment: This join would only work if the row's subject matches the wikilink's subject. But I'm trying to find all wikilinks that share the combined list of subjects of all items.

Comment: Currently I can make this work by retrieving a list of all subjects for the specified items (only one item shown here)

`SELECT ?subject WHERE { ?item dct:subject ?subject . FILTER (?item IN <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Artificial_intelligence>)) }  `

And then use this list to add:
`FILTER (?subject IN (<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Artificial_intelligence>)) `

Comment: I see - just to clarify, do you mean that the wikilink items of the given item `i` do have all subjects of `i`? like if `i` has subjects `s1,s2,s3` you want all wikilinkgs that have (at least?) all those subjects as well?

Comment: Correct. and `i` can be a list of items

Comment: is this ever the case? Do you have a Wikilink which would fulfill that requirement?

Comment: In my opinion, something like double negation could work here: `SELECT ?item ?resource WHERE {
 ?item <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLink> ?resource .  
FILTER (?item IN (<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Artificial_intelligence>)) 
 
filter not exists {
?item <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?itemSubject .
filter not exists {?resource <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?resourceSubject. FILTER(?itemSubject = ?resourceSubject)}

}}`

Comment: - it return only wikilinks `w` such there is no subject `s` of `i` that is not also subject of `w`. But it returns an empty resultset so it would be good if we have any example where it should return a row for sure